# Prevent the computer from suspending when idle

Tags: arch-linux, suspend

I am using arch linux with i3wm. If the computer is idle for I believe 10 minutes, the computer screen will go black. For some reason this causes a weird glitch with firefox which makes me have to restart the computer. So I want to prevent the computer from auto-suspending. Where/how can I do that?

I'd like to know how to do this without installing any packages.

Answer (score 2):

I added the following into my `.xinitrc` and it works fine:

```
xset s off
xset -dpms
xset s noblank
```

for further informations see the [man page of xset](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xset.1.html)

**EDIT:**
Just realised, my answer is already given in a comment on an other answer

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Caffeine-ng: https://github.com/caffeine-ng/caffeine-ng . It is a little status bar application that prevents the activation of both the screensaver and sleep / suspend mode.

You can install it on Arch Linux using the [AUR package caffeine-ng](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/caffeine-ng/):

```
$ wget https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/caffeine-ng.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf caffeine-ng.tar.gz
$ cd caffeine-ng/
$ makepkg
$ sudo pacman -U caffeine-ng-*-any.pkg.tar.xz
```

Comment: I'd rather do this without installing extra packages because:
1) I want to know how my system works and how to tweak its settings;
2) I don't like having too much packages bloating my system.

Comment: In that case, try:
```xset s noblank; xset s off; xset -dpms```